# How to implement this .htaccess in firebase?

Tags: firebase, .htaccess, firebase-hosting

I have this .htaccess for a PWA

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

I want to migrate the app to firebase, basically what it does is let's say I shared this link

`example.com/pwa/giftLink`

He gets redirected to PWA

`example.com/pwa`

And the PWA redirects him to `giftLink`. I don't want to do it via code, I prefer doing it via `firebase.json`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Firebase Hosting [rewrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites), the equivalent would be:

```
"hosting": {
  // ...

  // Add the "rewrites" attribute within "hosting"
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "/pwa{,/**}",
    "destination": "/pwa/index.html"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: What does the `**` mean? I had a look through the linked document and I see it used in various places, but not what it actually means?

Comment: It's a Glob, matching any file or folder in an arbitrary sub-directory. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#glob_pattern_matching