# .htaccess on Firebase Hosting

Tags: firebase, .htaccess, url-rewriting, firebase-hosting

Hey i know that i cant use a htaccess file fore Firebase hosting, but i wanted to ask if someone knows how to do this .htaccess in Firebase Hosting:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9._]+)?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

it should be in a Format like this:

```
"hosting": {
  // ...

  // Serves index.html for requests to files or directories that do not exist
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60260927/how-to-implement-this-htaccess-in-firebase and https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/f57609/how_to_implement_this_htaccess_in_firebase/ for example/ If your current `firebase.json` doesn't work, indicate which part you tried that doesn't work.

Comment: I read the 2 samples you showed (The links) but it looks like if they only say if someone opens that url refer him to that. But I want to refer to another url and send the data in the url (That what you write in the url as id (example.com/test should refer to example.com/user.php?id=test)